# How can I prove that $\: \operatorname{Pr}[Y=0] \leq (\operatorname{E}[Y^2] - (\operatorname{E}[Y])^2)/\operatorname{E}[Y^2] \:$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

How can I prove that $\: \operatorname{Pr}[Y=0] \leq (\operatorname{E}[Y^2] - (\operatorname{E}[Y])^2)/\operatorname{E}[Y^2] \:$?

I know, $\: \operatorname{Pr}[Y=0] \leq (\operatorname{E}[Y^2] - (\operatorname{E}[Y])^2)/\operatorname{E}[Y]^2 \:$ can be proved using Chebysev's Inequality.

But I am not able to prove that $\: \operatorname{Pr}[Y=0] \leq (\operatorname{E}[Y^2] - (\operatorname{E}[Y])^2)/\operatorname{E}[Y^2] \:$.

Comment: I see no difference in what you can and cannot prove?

Comment: @user133281 Different denominators in the upper bounds.

Comment: @RickyDemer Please do not introduce mathematical errors in a question when editing it.

Comment: @Did : $\:$ Did I do so here? $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: @RickyDemer Yes: $E(Y^2)\ne E(Y)^2$.

Answer (score 4):

Cauchy-Schwarz inequality applied to the product $Y\cdot\mathbf 1_A$ with $A=[Y\ne0]$ yields
$$
E[Y\cdot\mathbf 1_A]^2\leqslant E[Y^2]\cdot E[\mathbf 1_A^2].
$$
The LHS is $E[Y]^2$ because $Y\cdot\mathbf 1_A=Y$, and, in the RHS, $E[\mathbf 1_A^2]=P[A]$, hence
$$
E[Y]^2\leqslant E[Y^2]\cdot P[A],
$$
or, equivalently,
$$
P[Y=0]=1-P[A]\leqslant1-\frac{E[Y]^2}{E[Y^2]}.
$$